# Addition of values of the next row in r

Tags: r

I have a table that looks similar to:

```
   C1 C2 C3 C4 C5 C6
R1 2  3  5  7  8  8
R2 1  5  8  9  2  13 
R3 4  5  7  9  1
```

I want to create a new column "C6" such that the value is derived from R1C4 plus R2C1 giving 8 and repeating for the next row R2C4 plus R3C1 giving 13 in C6 and would like to repeat this for the entire table.

Help much appreciated. Many thanks.

Comment: A `table` or a `data.frame`? It makes a difference.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can use `lead` from `dplyr` here :

```
library(dplyr)
lead(df$C1) + df$C4

#[1]  8 13 NA
```

Answer (score 3):

We can use `base R` by removing the first element of 'C1', append `NA` at the end and add with 'C4' column

```
with(df1, c(C1[-1], NA) + C4)
#[1]  8 13 NA
```

Answer (score -1):

One can use `for` loop also for this:

```
for (r in 1:(nrow(ddf)-1)){
    ddf[r,'C6'] = ddf[r,'C4']+ ddf[r+1,'C1'] 
  }
```